# How do I share the whole entire link with google+, facebook, and linkedin?

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, sharing, google-plus

I am trying to use the 'share' links from the 3 social media sites, Google+, Facebook, and Linkedin. The links are working, but they are sharing the wrong URL.

For example, if my url is:

http://webdomain.com/index.html#/test/testpage12312.html

It will share this:

http://webdomain.com/index.html#

Anyone know why it is ignoring everything after the hash? Thanks.

Here are the URL's I'm using:

```
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=[URL]
http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=[URL]
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=http%3A%2F%2F%20[URL]
```

Answer (score 4):

You should encode the URL so the # character will be %23.